# How to get the edit text value out of the Anonymos class

Tags: android, dialog, alert

I am creating AlertDialog for inputting some data and I want to take it out from the Anonymous class created for the AlertDialog. Here is what I have:

```
    public void SetDescriptionDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage("Message");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    View v = input;
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Editable value = input.getText();
            out = value.toString();
            Log.i("INPUT + ", value.toString());
            // Do something with value!
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });

    alert.show();
}
```

out is global variable of type String.

Comment: What's the problem? Don't you have the value you want in `out`?

Comment: It crashes, it is still null at the point I need it in my program.

Comment: Once I call the function to cback create this AlertDialog to get the user data, the part following is actually not waiting for the dialog to be closed, and to have a valid value, instead it immediately continues after .show() is called, so when I use the value back in my function, it is null.

Comment: So just create a method and use the value there after you send it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onClick()` of the `Dialog` just send it to a method where you do what you need to

```
out = value.toString();
Log.i("INPUT + ", value.toString());
// Do something with value!
useOutput(out);
```

Then somewhere in your `Activity` create the method and put the code that uses it in there

```
private void useOutput(String sOutput)
{
    // do something with the value
}
```

Comment: Then you would have to explain how it fails. I have no idea what you are doing so couldn't tell you what you are doing wrong. There is also an `onDismiss()` that you can `Override` and do stuff there. But if this isn't working then it's likely that won't either until you figure out the root of the problem

Comment: My logic wasn't good, even if I was calling a function to deal with the value outside. I was using the value before it was even created, hence yielding null. Thanks.

Comment: I understood that part but that's why you would put it in this function and not use it until you had a value to pass to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bro for correcting me.
Bro. you need to create a static variable to store the value from the Dialog box. And then you can use it anywhere in your Activity.

If you want to apply it to some widget of Activity like (TextView), you can directly setText in your setPosituveButton.

Comment: No, bro, the problem wasn't with wanting to take out the `Dialog` code. It was with trying to use a value that was assigned inside the `Dialog`

Comment: You're welcome but this still doesn't help. The OP has it as a member variable stated in the post, "out is global variable of type String.". The problem has been solved that it was the logic of trying to use the variable before it was given a value.

Comment: Great dear, you are champ :)

Answer (score 0):

make your variable **global** and **static** so that you can call it in every class just by calling **YourClass.yourVariable;**

Comment: Read the entire post and comments. This is being done, "out is global variable of type String."